# openseadragon svg overlay - clickable area is too large

Tags: d3.js, svg, openseadragon

I am working with an OpenSeaDragon image with an overlay (array of overlays?) that has about 500 clickable svg rect elements, implemented using the Overlay.onclick() function

The bounding rectangle for the clickable area varies but is always much larger than the visible rectangle, and often covers neighboring rectangles as well.  I have tried messing with margin, border, and padding to no avail.  This image show an example, showing the difference. The actual displayed rectangle is the same dimension as the visible text box, while the clickable area is the entire highlighted rectangle.

There does not seem to be a lot of predictability - the clickable area varies in an apparently random way but is always larger than the correct size, up to about twice in both directions.  As shown, it's not always centered - I'm not sure it ever is.  The proportions remain the same when the image is zoomed in and out.

I'm fairly new at JS, and this involves so many components including D3 and the OSD suite, that I'm not sure where to start.  Any suggestions would be appreciated!

[image: screenshot cutout from openseadragon]

For reference, here is the code where the boxes are generated from an array.  This was adapted from a single rectangle example, and I have no idea if this was a good way to do this.  (I would have liked to have the inside of the box fully transparent except when mousing over it, but that's a whole other problem...)

```
var overlay = this.viewer.svgOverlay();
len = nodes.length;
var d3Rect = [];
var url    = [];
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var mynode = nodes[i];
    d3Rect[i] = d3.select(overlay.node()).append("rect")
        .style('fill', '#ffffff')
        .style('fill-opacity', '0.05')
        .style('stroke', '#000066')
        .style('stroke-width', '0.0005')
        .style('stroke-opacity', '0.5')
        .attr("x",      mynode.x1)
        .attr("width",  mynode.width)
        .attr("y",      mynode.y1)
        .attr("height", mynode.height)
        .attr("title",  mynode.title)
        .attr("href",  mynode.link);

    overlay.onClick(d3Rect[i].node(), function() {
        window.open(this.element.getAttribute("href"), '_blank');
    });
}
```

Comment: Do you have it running somewhere you can link to? That would be helpful in debugging it.

Comment: Yes, see http://hebegb.homeunix.net/t2/view-isp-tool.html - unfortunately I can't leave it up at this location permanently but it will be up for a month or so.  It will eventually be available on http://thespaceplan.com, once we get the problems ironed out. This is, of course, hacked-up html, hacked-up css, and hacked-up js.  I've been away from this side of things for a long time, and I started from pieces of various examples. :P

Comment: It's actually looking pretty good to me… Some of the yellow rectangles are a little off, but that's probably just a data issue. Does that mean you got it sorted out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The visible rectangles are (mostly) correct as you've noted.  But if you click on any rectangle it may or may not work.  For example, if you click on the first element under Robotic Exploration, "Near Earth Asteroid Rendezvous", it will correctly open up a page in another window/tab that presents data about that topic.  But if you click on the next box down, "Lunar Prospector", you will zoom in - you won't get the relevant page.  If you "Inspect Element" on the "Near Earth Asteroid Rendezvous, the blue clickable area covers both of those boxes and parts of others.

Comment: I see! Yes, this definitely looks like a rounding issue. If I change the coordinates for the SVG object, the rounded rectangle moves but the element's click box does not. You should do as I suggest below and multiply everything by 1000 or so; that should take care of it.

Comment: Incidentally, I can repro the issue in Mac Firefox but not Chrome.

Comment: Excellent, I will try that. I have been unable to look at this since your earlier post, as we are prepping for a big presentation at the international space development conference, so I had to shelve this until some other things got done. But if I can fix with rescaling then that should be something I can test quickly.  I'm flying up in a couple of days so I still might not get to it until I get back, but you have given me hope. Interesting that the browsers handle it differently. Ive mostly been using Firefox.

Comment: Sounds good. I suppose meanwhile you can demo in Chrome.

Comment: I forked svgoverlay and use image coordinates instead of viewport coordindates. See if it helps: https://github.com/leesei/openseadragon-svg/blob/master/openseadragon/openseadragon-svg-overlay2.js.

Comment: I'm finally getting back to work. langilman - I'm a bit confused - my understanding is that the SVG has to be in the 0-1 range (in X).  If it's in the 0-1000 range, how do I map that to the underlying image?  I'm going to do some doc and code reading to see if I can figure it out, but I thought I'd post here as well. leesei - I'll check that out as well, thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but it looks like you are creating 1 overlay element of unknown size, then adding all the rects inside it, and then binding the click event to the top overlay instead of the individual rects.

In any case, if the shapes you need are simple rects, you should try using
 
`viewer.addOverlay( element, location, placement, onDraw )`

[link to docs](https://openseadragon.github.io/examples/ui-overlays/)

Comment: @user2757511 is using https://github.com/openseadragon/svg-overlay and that overlay.onClick is the correct way to bind to the individual rectangles... good to check though! As for using regular HTML overlays rather than the svg-overlay plugin, that's definitely worth trying if the SVG overlay can't be made to behave. My only concern is that 500 HTML overlays might be slower than with SVG.

Comment: The SVG overlays are reasonably fast - I recently added another set for the elements around the sides, and I think this was when I first noticed any actual delay.  Most of the startup time is, of course, bringing in all of the tiles.  I _would_ like to have each box highlight in some form when mouseover, in addition or instead of the 'title' method, showing the actual location of the box.  But for now that's a future exercise. :) Maybe an additional method in svg-overlay, like onClick()?

Comment: I'll just add that I had pondered an alternative method, which was to have one overlay over the whole thing, and create a single box that appeared under the mouse whenever it was in an appropriate location, rather than define all the boxes in advance.  I don't know enough javascript if this would work, much less how to do it or whether it's a good idea.

Comment: If all you want is a hover highlight, just moving an individual overlay to the   hovered location works great; that's what I'm doing with http://iangilman.com/osd/test/demo/m2/ … You can see the code for that demo here: https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/blob/master/test/demo/m2/js/main.js On the other hand, if you don't even want that but just need to handle clicks in all the different locations, you don't even need an overlay. Just handle clicks on the canvas and do the math yourself to figure out where the click landed.

Comment: Hover overlay and a computed location for the click may be the solution if I can figure out how to make it work.  It's not quite the same as your example but I'll check it out.  My input data has the X and Y extents as well as width and height, and I have the original pixel coordinates in my original data.  So I do have the necessary data if I can figure it out (and no simple solution to the stated problem appears).  Bonus - we get to eventually do a real zoom in where as you go in, the other data disappears and more detailed boxes come into view >_>! That's a whole other project though.

Comment: Sounds cool! There are lots of possibilities once you get the basics together.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you're running into precision problems. What are the dimensions of your image in viewport coordinates? By default the width would be 1, but this might cause rounding issues when zoomed in on these SVG elements. Try making your image 1000 wide and multiply all of your overlay coordinates by 1000 and see if that helps.

Comment: I am thinking along the same lines.  I believe the default is still the case - the width is 1, the length is more - 1.4 or thereabouts (the aspect ratio is 30x48).  In the console, I am logging the mouse position, and it seems to coincide exactly with the box that is drawn.  The box (rounded corners, etc.) is passed to the overlay in viewport coordinates (x in {0, 1}  BTW - I made the box outline show up in yellow for visibility.

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the suggested fix? Any luck?

Comment: I forked svgoverlay and use image coordinates instead of viewport coordindates. See if it helps: https://github.com/leesei/openseadragon-svg/blob/master/openseadragon/openseadragon-svg-overlay2.js.

Comment: I'm back in the saddle - I took a longer than expected vacation.  I can scale the numbers in the source svg, but I don't know how to set the width to something other than 1.  (BTW - the image is 3000x4800.)  I'm searching the code and docs, but thought it would be worthwhile to post in the meantime.

Comment: Re the forked version.  I had to add the onClick function to your forked code, and the viewport.dimension.x and y were null, so I substituted the image dimensions - 1200 and 1920. With those two changes I am getting little boxes but their location and size seem to be scaled a bit less than 1/2 in both directions. The size of the entire svg layer is correct though. Again, still looking around to see if I can figure this out.

Comment: Offtopic - I found a syntax error in the viewerinputhook.js code.  Lines 120-123 need quotes around the strings. AFAIK this is not related to my issue.

Comment: Using the forked version (thanks leesei!) I now have something almost working.  I added a scaling factor of 2.07 to my code in both X and Y. (also width and height), and this put the boxes in exactly the right place.  :)

Comment: FYI, the latest version is at hebegb.homeunix.net/t2/new-view.html :) Definite progress.  (NB: some of the boxes are missing in the SVG, and a few have incorrect data). Any quick suggestions on how to highlight boxes using mouseover?

Comment: How are you managing clicks for the boxes? You should be able to add mouse over the same way. Good catch on ViewerInputHook; can you file an issue at https://github.com/msalsbery/OpenSeadragonViewerInputHook/issues? Bravo on your progress!